# Apple Push Notification service PHP cpu usage too high. how can I Improve performance?

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

My task is sending push notification to multiple users which is working fine with following function

```
function push_to_apns_badge($token_array)
{
    $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $pem_path  = MODULE_DIR.'push_notification'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $apnsCert = $pem_path.'apns-dev.pem';

    if(is_array($token_array) && count($token_array))
    {       
        foreach ($token_array as $token)
        {
            $streamContext = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

            $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
            $badge_count = (int)$token['badge'];
            $payload = get_payload_badge($badge_count);

            $apnsMessage = get_one_message_to_write_badge($token['token'],$payload);
            $wrt = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage); 

            $_error_str .= " $error $errorString ";
            socket_close($apns);
            fclose($apns);
        }
    }   
    return array(true,$_error_str); 
}
```

But it will take too much cpu usage.

Can I improve Performance somehow? or something missing there?

Thanks

Comment: Is this for live ultimately or just for testing?  Apple will not like you opening and closing lots of connections to the APNS servers. You need to keep the connection open!  Have you looked at Urban Airship?

Comment: Its for live. Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making too many connections to Apple and they could block you if you do it this way.

I suspect the creating and tearing down of the connection with each message is also your slow point there!

Apple recommend opening a connection, sending your messages, leaving it open for as long as you can, and to send future messages down that same connection too.

You may want to look at Urban Airship which will send 1 million messages a month free?

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can do it for free using apns-php

http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/

- A nice easy to use APNS class which you can queue up a bunch of messages and send them at once with.

My client currently pays a fortune for UA and we're moving away from them.